# Why isset doesn't return true when I override magic functions __get and __set

Tags: php

I had the following code.

May I know, why `isset` doesn't return true, when I override magic functions `__get` and `__set`

The output I get is

```
$param->country : US
isset($param->country) :
```

---

```
<?php

class Param
{
    private $params = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->params[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->params[$name] = $value;
    }
}

$param = new Param();
$param->country = "US";
echo "\$param->country : " . $param->country . "\n";
echo "isset(\$param->country) : " . isset($param->country) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__set` and `__get` do not handle `isset`. You will have to implement [the magic method `__isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset) as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's by design.
`isset` is not a function, it's a language construct and it does not automagically call `__get`. That's why there's an `__isset` magic method [also](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset).

You'll need PHP >= 5.1.0 though.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `isset` is a language construct which does not call the magic methods, you should also implement the magic method `__isset`.

See also the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset